# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'embed' before initialization

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Here is my code, but I don't know to where should I put that "*const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()*" line.

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "events",
  description: "Display the events!",
  execute(message, bot, args){
    message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("Event Times")
  .setDescription("Server's timezone: UTC+3")
  .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/Jk5Wxj3.png")
  .addFields(
      { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
      { name: 'Monday', value: 'DemaNeR - Start 8AM' }, // Value is the event name and time.
      { name: 'Tuesday', value: 'Spaceball - Start 6PM' }, // value: 'new value'
      { name: 'Wednesday', value: 'JPB- Start 10PM' },
      { name: 'Thursday', value: 'Invasion - Start 9PM' },
      { name: 'Friday', value: 'Hitac - Start 4PM' },
      { name: 'Saturday', value: 'CVC(Infiltration) - All Day' },
      { name: 'Sunday', value: 'JPB - Start 7PM ->> Invasion - Start 10PM' },
  )
  .setColor("#f36639")

}

  }
```

Comment: You could put if above `module.exports`

Comment: You will find your code easier to debug if you indent properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `embed` before you defined it.

```
execute(message, bot, args) {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        /* code omitted for brevity */       
    message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved!

Comment: @W3X common courtesy would be to upvote the correct answer too

Answer (score 0):

just switch these two lines

```
   message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
```

to be

```
   const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
   message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
```