# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'embed' before initialization (hi)

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: "slowmode",
    description: "Set the slowmode of a channel.",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            return message.reply("You don't have enough perms to use this command!")
        }
    
        let duration = args[0]
        if(isNaN(duration)) return message.reply("Please give the time in seconds.")
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if(!reason) return message.reply("Please specify a reason!")

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

            .setTitle("SlowMode!")
            .addFields(
                {name: 'Mod', value: 'message.author.tag'},
                {name: 'Reason', value: 'message.author.tag has set the slowmode to ${duration} because ${reason}'},

                message.channel.sendEmbed(embed)

            )
    }
}
```

thats my code and whenever i try to send the embed i get the error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'embed' before initialization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: Cannot access 'embed' before initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089459/referenceerror-cannot-access-embed-before-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

The error means you're trying to access the value of `embed` before you declared it.

The problem is you're assigning the functions return values into `embed` instead of creating the instance and then calling the functions.

What you should do is something like that:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
embed.setTitle("SlowMode!")
    .addFields(
    { name: 'Mod', value: 'message.author.tag' },
    { name: 'Reason', value: 'message.author.tag has set the slowmode to ${duration} because ${reason}'}
);
message.channel.sendEmbed(embed)
```